# Are string saved to arrays permanently saved?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, arrays

I'm an 11-year-old learning how to code Javascript, I recently started 1 and a half months ago. I am making a login/register system and am trying to make the register part now. I was wondering if adding a **string/number/boolean** to an **array stays there forever (even after refresh).** I would've used cookies for this, but it is not safe.

I am currently using `HTML5`, `CSS3`, `Javascript`, and **eventually** will be using `Jquery`. ***NOTE: The time period does not have to be forever.***  Does any know the answer to this, please reply?
P.S. ( iff you mention PHP for this there would be no point, I don't understand it yet. :/ )

Comment: The short answer is that the array and all of your variables go away after you refresh the page.  If you want to make a login/register system, you will have to save the information somewhere on a "back end", using PHP, Ruby, Node, or something like that.  Unfortunately, learning web programming requires both parts.

Comment: As a side note, you don't need jquery.  It's awesome, and we used it years ago when javascript had fewer features.  All of the best parts of jquery are now part of javascript.

Comment: If you want to store data, you have to either use cookies or [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: You will not be able to create a registration system with only client-side code. You must store the credentials in a way that the user can't control and one that will live longer than a particular browser session. For that reason, you'll need to learn a bit about server-side technologies.

Comment: Or try IndexedDb

Comment: a string or whatever you have in an array will not stay in it forever simply because an array is a `data structure` which is not persistent. I suggest you use a `localStorage` to implement the registration feature for your app. because whatever you save in a `sessionStorage` will be wiped off when you close the tab this can be handy in the implementation of you `login` and `logout` feature for now. Whenever you upgrade the applications to more sophisticated technologies you will have a better way to handle those features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a string or whatever you have in an array will not stay in it forever simply because an array is a [data structure](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-structures/) which is not persistent. Since you have it in your intention to use more advanced technologies in the near future and you are not comfortable with the `cookie` because of the obvious security risks. I suggest you use a `localStorage` to implement the registration feature for your app. Of course you can achieve the same with a `sessionStorage`, however whatever you save in a `sessionStorage` will be wiped off when you close the tab which can be handy in the implementation of you `login` and `logout` feature for now. Whenever you upgrade the applications to more sophisticated technologies you will have a better way to handle those features.

PS: it might be a little advanced for you right now but when you are more comfortable writing Javascript maybe you will like to checkout `IndexDB` then NodeJs very much later.
#cheers #dontRelent

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. Note that anytime you reload a browser page, your JavaScript also reloads with the page.
If you want you data to persist, use a database.

Comment: We tend not to "answer" these kinds of simple questions that are likely to be closed for one reason or another. Instead, we just provide a "comment" to the OP as you can see several of us have. Work on getting your reputation up to the point where you can comment until then.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you're storing that array. If you want to make a functional login/register on a web-page, you will likely need to use a database such as *PostgreSQL*.

However, if you want to just create a simple program to run on the command line, the username or password strings you enter in will not remain in memory if you terminate the program. If you terminate your program, it will delete the strings added to your array.

Comment: We tend not to "answer" these kinds of simple questions that are likely to be closed for one reason or another. Instead, we just provide a "comment" to the OP as you can see several of us have. Work on getting your reputation up to the point where you can comment until then.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create login functionality, you will have to start learning some server-side technologies.

When I was finished (kind of) with learning JavaScript i moved on to NodeJS and MongoDB. NodeJS allows you use JavaScript on the server-side and MongoDB is a database program where you could store data.

Using those two you would create a user model, store it and then check if the user is logged in and etc.

There are many choices to go with when learning back-end, I went with NodeJS because as I already knew JavaScript it was easier to use the same language for the back-end. That and it was part of the Udemy course I had.

Good luck.